# How to name packages correctly when using Maven?

Tags: java, maven

I created a maven project, by convention we should put our packages in /src/main/java.

When I create a new package there, if I name it for instance "mypackage" , the package name will not take into account the namespace that I specified in the pom file, i.e "org.company.mypackage"

I end up having a class that looks like this :

```
package mypackage; // instead of org.company.mypackage

public class MyClass {
    public void myMethod() {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: How or with what tool are you creating your packages/classes?  Most Java IDEs (Eclipse, IntelliJ, etc.) usually get this right automatically.

Comment: "the package name will not take into account the namespace" And it shouldn't, there's no rule or constraint enforcing it. The code of your project is for your project and whatever depends on it (imports) the maven definitions is to define it as an artifact. It is just convention

Answer (score 6):

The Maven "namespace" (the `groupId`) in the pom is not automatically prepended to Java packages. You have to do that manually (unless your IDE has some special functionality to do that for you)

Its a common convention to use the `groupId` and `artifactId` as base package of your project, but that is not enforced. If your pom contains

```
<groupId>org.company</groupId>
<artifactId>myproject</artifactId>
```

then all Java packages should start with `org.company.myproject`, e.g.  `org.company.myproject.mypackage`.